# python str replace '\'

Tags: string, python-2.7

i'm new to python, i wrote script that query from db, and getting path looking like this:

```
...\\dev$\\AUTOMATION\\Logs\14-01-16_15-50-57_143
```

when i print the result i see that:

```
the \14 
change to hexa-  x0c
```

i want to access this link, in order to do so i need to add \ so the link will look like this:

```
...\\dev$\\AUTOMATION\\Logs\\14-01-16_15-50-57_143
```

I tried to os.path.dirname
re.find split and didnt get what i needed.
please i tried so many suggestions i saw in xda and non helped me.

Thanks,

---

Thanks for the response.
I know the escape , like: r'MyString', or \ when there is \
The problem is that i get the path from DB
and in the DB the path i receive is like this  .. \AUTOMATION\Logs\15-01-16_15-50-57_143

and python load it immediately to x0c

I hope the problem sounds more clear..

Thnaks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

Answer (score 0):

When you print a string, you need to escape the backslashes with another backslash. `\14` is getting read as a hex value, but `\\14` will be printed correctly.